# Gsutil sync vs cp -n

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync, cp, gsutil

I am looking to routinely back up a number of GCS buckets, and sometimes these buckets can contain a huge number of files (upwards of 200,000, total file size of 5tb-ish).

Using multithreaded/multiprocess rsync still seems to take too long to build up the synchronization state (this needs to take <20 mins).

Would using the cp no-clobber (-n) option potentially speed things up? Or will that spend the same building up the synchronization state as rsync? Thanks.

Comment: where do you run gsutil command?

Comment: and as well What kind of Storage the buckets are?  What location and class? Can you add some more information?

Comment: And where are you store the backups of your buckets?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the average file size of the objects you are transferring. Do you have many small files, then I would recommend not to use the -n (no-clobber). Because for every file, it has to send a request to check if the file is already present.

In your case, your average file size is around 25mb. I never did any test on finding the breaking-even point for using the no-clobber option. But in your case, I think it could be helpful to speed up things a bit. But if you'd had files of averaging over 100mb, the impact would be much higher.

A good thing to know, price is not a factor, because GCP ingress is free. If the price would be a factor you would of course choose the no-clobber option, to transfer fewer data.

> No-clobber. When specified, existing files or objects at the
> destination are not replaced. Any items that are skipped by this
> option are reported as skipped. gsutil performs an additional GET
> request to check if an item exists before attempting to upload the
> data. This saves gsutil from retransmitting data, but the additional
> HTTP requests may make small object transfers slower and more
> expensive.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options)